# Subdomain Redirects To Main Domain Apache Virtual Host

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, subdomain

I am in Ubuntu 14.04 running Apache 2.4 on a Digital Ocean droplet.

I am trying to get a subdomain to point to a different directory than the main domain, all on the same droplet (same IP address).

My DNS records and networking:

```
CNAME   
*.example.com is an alias of 
example.com.    
CNAME   
*.old.example.com is an alias of 
old.example.com.
A   
old.example.com directs to 
M.Y.I.P. 
NS  
example.com directs to 
ns3.digitalocean.com. 
A   
example.com directs to 
M.Y.I.P.
NS  
example.com directs to 
ns1.digitalocean.com. 
NS  
example.com directs to 
ns2.digitalocean.com.
```

My virtual host files that I've already enabled using `a2ensite`

**example.com:**

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html
   <Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html>
```

**old.example.com:**

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@old.example.com
    ServerName old.example.com
    ServerAlias *.old.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/old.example.com/public_html/magento
    <Directory /var/www/html/old.example.com/public_html/magento>
```

So why is it not working? Can you not do a subdomain to a different directory on the same IP? The Digital Ocean guide had the subdomain pointing to a different droplet, but that's not what I want.

Is `CNAME *.example.com is an alias of example.com.` the problem? As in, is it intercepting the `old` part of the subdomain? If so, is there a way to reorder it so that `random.example.com` still leads to `example.com`?

Thank you.

**Edit:** To clarify, I put `old.example.com` into my browser and it flashes for a second as if redirecting, and then it resolves to `example.com` and serves that domain's directory content (`/var/www/html/example.com/public_html`) instead of the content of `old.example.com`

**Edit 2:**

Htaccess in `old.example.com` DocumentRoot

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none

###########################################
## Deny access to cron.php
    <Files cron.php>

############################################
## uncomment next lines to enable cron access with base HTTP authorization
## http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html
##
## Warning: .htpasswd file should be placed somewhere not accessible from the web.
## This is so that folks cannot download the password file.
## For example, if your documents are served out of /usr/local/apache/htdocs
## you might want to put the password file(s) in /usr/local/apache/.

        #AuthName "Cron auth"
        #AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
        #AuthType basic
        #Require valid-user

############################################

        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all

    </Files>
```

**Edit 3:** My output of `apache2ctl -S`

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf:1)
                 wild alias *.example.com
         port 80 namevhost old.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/old.example.com.conf:1)
                 wild alias *.old.example.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

Is `default server example.com` the problem? I tried to disable the default using `a2dissite default` which yielded nothing.

**Edit 4:** I renabled `000-default.conf` as the default but the problem still persists, no matter what I always get redirected to `example.com` rather than going to my desired `old.example.com`

Comment: OK that's closer. So what is in the address bar then?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The address bar resolves to `http://example.com/`

Comment: OK, remember to add this information to your question, where others can see it.

Comment: I guess that its the code of the site that redirect to the http://example.com/. Is this a wordpress installation? If so then this is a standard behavior.

Comment: @VikelidisKostas Not a wordpress installation, it's a Magento that isn't configured yet so it shouldn't be redirecting.

Comment: Maybe an .htaccess file? Can we have a listing of the DocumentRoot path?

Comment: @VikelidisKostas See edits, I added the .htaccess served in the DocumentRoot path of `old.example.com`, please lmk if this isn't what you wanted. It's just the default Magento `.htaccess`

Comment: Try to remove Magento files from the document root clear your browser's cache and try again. If the problem remains that means that it's a web server configuration issue if the problem is solved then it's magento related.

Comment: @VikelidisKostas Pointed to a completely different directory with no Magento files and the problem remains, so it isn't Magento specific.